# Does serialized content strictly follow the order in definition use encoding/json package?

Tags: json, go

I use `encoding/json`to serialize struct. I'm confused about the output of `json.Marshal` function. Does the serialized field content strictly follow the order in the struct definition?

e.g. Here is a struct definition

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Field1  string
    Field2  string
}
```

could the output be `{"Field2":"field2","Field1":"field1"}`? Since if the output struct fields out of order, the hash of the serialized content will be uncertain.

Comment: The only way to make custom behaviour is creating custom marshaller that implements ```json.Marshaler```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current implementation is deterministic, e.g. for structs see https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L629 which gives struct order (and maps are by sorted keys).

But as this is *not* guaranteed by the documentation you should consider this an implementation detail.

If you want to hash the output you'll face more problems, e.g. there are several equivalent representations of characters in strings and JSON has no notion of an int (floats only). It really depends on what you try to do wirh that hash.

Comment: It is now documented that map keys are sorted https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15424

Answer (score 4):

> Does the serialized field content strictly follow the order in the struct definition?

No.  There is no guarantee of this. In practice, while it may be true for many data types, such as structs, it will certainly not be true for maps, and one should never depend on the order remaining the same, as implementation details can change between Go versions or even Go compilers, and if you assume consistent ordering in such cases, you could introduce bugs.

If ordering is important for your specific data types, you can implement a custom [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) that preserves order.